# Handle an event multiple levels deep

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling, progress-bar

I'm not quite sure where to go with this problem.

I have a .net VB winform that has a document manager tab in it. When I drag and drop a document I call a UploadService class, which then creates an UploadClient class Which then creates a CustomStream class that raises a ProgressChanged Event as the stream is being read.

Is there anyway that I can make the documentmanager handle the event of ProgressChanged that far deep? I'm pretty new with handlers and Trying to figure out the best way to do it.

I thought of making the CustomStream Object in the document manager and pass it down lower to listen to it, but I know that's not the way this should be done. Is it recommended to bubble up the event?

The object that fires off the event (my custom stream) has a getProgress() method that I want to call so that I can update a progress bar in the winform.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can only suggest you implement cascading events, so that UploadClient handles CustomStream.ProgressChanged and fires UploadClient.ProgressChanged, which is handled by UploadService the way it suits you.

Comment: Thank you! this is the solution I used. I would of liked a more elegant solution, but this seems to be the easiest to implement. thank you once again